# Как сделать плавное появление главного окна при запуске? такое возможно? (QtDesigner)

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qt-designer, qpropertyanimation

Как сделать плавное появление главного окна при запуске? 
Такое возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *Qt Designer* - нет. 
Класс `QPropertyAnimation` анимирует свойства Qt.

Больше... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QApplication


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Click me', self, clicked=self.doClose))

        # Класс анимации прозрачности окна
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)        # Продолжительность: 1 секунда

        # Выполните постепенное увеличение
        self.doShow()

    def doShow(self):
        try:
            self.animation.finished.disconnect(self.close)
        except:
            pass
        self.animation.stop()
        # Диапазон прозрачности постепенно увеличивается от 0 до 1.
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()

    def doClose(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)  # Закройте окно, когда анимация будет завершена
        # Диапазон прозрачности постепенно уменьшается с 1 до 0.
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]